# jQuery: Event is attached to button, but fires at image element inside button in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such button in form:

```
<button class="delete-file-btn" "><img src="/img/del.png"/></button>
```

Then I attach event via jQuery:

```
$('#Form').on('click', 'button.delete-file-btn', function(e) {
    // Some code here
});
```

When I press the button in Crome, e.target points at img element, but not button. What's wrong with event assignment? in FF everything works fine.

Comment: You should be able to use `this` to get the `button`.

Comment: `e.currentTarget` or `this` refers to the clicked element in that context.

Comment: Or, using event bubbling, comparing `this` to `$('.delete-file-btn').get(0)` and performing an action when true could help. Event bubbling dictates that the click will bubble up to that `button` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `e.target` refers to the most specific element you clicked on, the element you targeted. The event is fired because your target is a child of the element you attached the `click` on. Use `this` to refer to the element you attached the eventhandler on.

When I try your example I do get the image as `e.target`, also in firefox.

I hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this is related or not.. But it appears you have an extra quote (") in your `<button/>` tag. This could be throwing off Chrome but not FF.

I just tested this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhk29jr7/)) and by looking at the console log I indeed see `button.delete-file-btn` as the `currentTarget`.

Comment: No, extra " is left after I removed some extra attributes. HTML is correct here.

Comment: Can you post more of your code then? Maybe make a [Plunkr?](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue). Because I just tested this on JSFiddle and it works fine. Even in your question you can clearly see an extra (").

Comment: Actually tip above solved the problem, it was pretty easy. Thanks!